# Backup Exec Completing Successfully - but not getting all files?

Tags: backup, file-management, symantec

I have a file server and I noticed that when I run a backup that should pull around 800 GB to tape it is only pulling around 10 GB. The job says it is completing successfully and the selection list appears to be correct. Any ideas why this might be occurring? I mirror the data to another server - so I tried the same job on that computer with the same result. Why is it skipping so many files? And why is it not failing when it does? I'm running BE 2010.

Comment: You might want to try the official BE forum if no one here knows the answer: http://www.symantec.com/connect/backup-and-archiving/forums/backup-exec

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the size of the backups is not exactly the best way to determine that the backup is not complete. Have you looked at the restore catalogs for the jobs in question? If so, what do they show?

Comment: +1 Try restoring some random files as well. Is the dedup option installed? That can really save some space.